# From kinetics rate to individual probabilities

Tags: probability, mathematical-modeling

I'm building an agent-based model for convection-reaction simulations. Basically my particles are moving at a certain speed in their environment and when they encounter receptors they can bind to them with a certain probability. I want this probability to be a function of their speed -the faster you go the less chance you have to bind-.

To have realistic numbers, I'm looking at binding rates, expressed in second-1 or molecule-1.second-1. Do you have any idea how I could turn these rates into individual probabilities, if it's even possible ? Or if I should look more into having the receptors pick some particles around them every time step, and the slower particles would have a greater cumulated probability of being picked, since they spend more time around the receptor ?

I feel like I might have to look at something like Gillespie algorithm, but not sure how, because I really want to keep the agent-based structure.

Comment: I think it depends on how exactly you want the binding probabilities to scale with the speed. The "linear" model would be that the binding probability decreases with speed, simply because the binding time is a random variable, such that the particle binds to the receptor if and only if it stays in the neighborhood of the receptor for the length of the binding time. A "nonlinear" model would have an actual coupling between the speed and the binding probability. Your choice here would depend on the application, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Gillespie's algorithm considers a **well-stirred population**. So it does not track the individual positions of the molecules, but rather counts their total number (regardless of their position). So, you can't use it. You should instead assume a model of how such probability depends on the things that you are tracking, as Ian is suggesting.

Comment: I'm sure one can make adjustments to the boiler-plate Gillespie, e.g. in some spatially heterogenous reaction system no? Anyway, just a heads up that Gillespie simulations are discussed acrosss multiple biological organisational scales in Stack Biology: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52304/is-this-adaption-of-the-gillespie-algorithm-using-michaelis-constants-justifiabl, and http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/16580/5005

Comment: Yes of course, but accounting for spatial structures requires major changes (even for the baseline theory).